# How to check if X509Certificate is CA certificate?

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, ca

I have a X509Certificate instance in Java and I need to identify if it is a CA certificate or user certificate.

Can anyone provide any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have asked several questions that have been answered. You should mark the answers as accepted to give back to the community.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized how to do it. Thanks for pointing me to accept the answer..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to research I have performed, it can be checked by checking basic constraints!
Check the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getBasicConstraints) for returning results of `getBasicConstraints()` method.

So if the method returns result `!= -1`, a certificate can be considered as a `CA certificate`.

I have checked this with several `CA certificates` (root and intermediate), and it works as described.
I have also checked this method with several user certificates, and the method returns -1 as result.

Comment: I think I have found an exception to this rule on Android. On most API versions ( greater that API 15) this works as described but on API17 it would return `!= -1` on both CA and user certificates.

Comment: Only on API17  or on API17+? I'm not involved in Android development, so I haven't tried out this on different API versions.

Comment: Only on API 17. I ended up using the double check - first `getBasicConstraints()!= -1` and after that `certificate.getKeyUsage()[5] == true`. My reading of Oracle documentation made me think this is possible and I have not found fault in this method so far. Here is a link to the documentation [X509Certificate Java6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getBasicConstraints). Java 7 does not introduce changes to this functionality.

Comment: Is there some way using which we can also identify which (the name itself) CA actually signed the cert ? Checking the issuer name could be one way, I guess, but that may not be too reliable, I suppose.

Comment: I ended up checking `!certificate.getKeyUsage()[5]` Refer to answer by @dpinya

Answer (score 13):

X509Certificate.getKeyUsage() javadoc:

> gets a boolean array representing bits of the KeyUsage extension, (OID
>   = 2.5.29.15). The key usage extension defines the purpose (e.g., encipherment, signature, certificate signing) of the key contained in
>   the certificate. The ASN.1 definition for this is:
>
> ```
>           KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
>               digitalSignature        (0),
>               nonRepudiation          (1),
>               keyEncipherment         (2),
>               dataEncipherment        (3),
>               keyAgreement            (4),
>               keyCertSign             (5),  --> true ONLY for CAs
>               cRLSign                 (6),
>               encipherOnly            (7),
>               decipherOnly            (8) }
> ```

A certificate can be checked as follow:

```
X509Certificate cert = ...;
boolean[] keyUsage = cert.getKeyUsage();
if ( keyUsage[5] ) {
    // CA certificate
}
else {
    // User certificate
}
```

Comment: One may need to check if the `keyUsage` array is not null as `Returns null if this certificate does not contain a KeyUsage extension.`

Comment: Key usage is not the same thing as Basic Constaints CA: true. You can have a CA: true certificate, without any key usage set.

Comment: From RFC 5280, section "4.2.1.3.  Key Usage": "Conforming CAs MUST include this extension in certificates that contain public keys that are used to validate digital signatures on other public key certificates or CRLs.  When present, conforming CAs SHOULD mark this extension as critical". You can have a CA without key usage, but not a conformant CA.

Answer (score 2):

A Root CA will be a self signed certificate with the `keyCertSign` flag enabled. In most scenarios the common name may include the word `CA` for convenience. An intermediate `CA` certificate may be signed by a `Root CA` (or another Intermediate!). Your brower key store will have examples of commonly trusted CA certificates.

From [The Internet Engineering Task Force](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459.txt)

```
The keyCertSign bit is asserted when the subject public key is
    used for verifying a signature on certificates.  This bit may only
    be asserted in CA certificates.
```

Comment: Oh, and look at slims answer for the how to in Java!

Comment: Interoperability and standards out the window! Depending on your app, you will just have to make a call, i.e. guess CA, Client or provide some mechanism to let the user decide. Each of these scenarios are dangerous. You are probably caught in the hard place where you have usability vs security to balance. To strict and it dosent work, too lax and its a security hole. You might need to make the assumption that a users certificate chain must be signed by one of a set of allowable root CA's (e.g. ones included in JVM). I think you will have to provide options and force your supervisor to decide.